# Why does the Android NDK miss out on certain API levels?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've just installed the latest Android Studio and Android NDK. When examining the `platforms` directory of my NDK installation, I can see the following platforms:

```
android-9
android-12
android-13
android-14
android-15
android-16
android-17
android-18
android-19
android-21
android-22
android-23
android-24
```

You can see that the API levels 10, 11, 20 and 25 are missing in the NDK. So why is that?

And what if my app should target API level 11? What should I define as `ANDROID_PLATFORM` in that case? I've tried the following and it seems to work although there is no `android-11` directory in my NDK:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-11',
                  '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to target API level 11? It's slightly confusing to me because it seems to work but as I said, there is no `android-11` directory in my NDK installation...

Thanks for anybody who can shed some light onto this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question in [NDK guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html). The bottom line is, not all system upgrades involved changes to public (stable) native APIs, and therefore don't have a separate directory under `platforms`. For example, to have your native libs compatible with API 11 (HONEYCOMB) you should use `platforms/android-9`.

Android NDK in general, and specifically CMake utilities for Android Studio, are aware of this rule, and explicitly enforce it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/cmake-utils/+/b36b6831eb5c4cd1640bf4940cfacb1c31e34366/android.toolchain.cmake#156).

Please note that recent NDK (r14) has dropped support for platforms below API 9 (GINGERBREAD).

**Update** there is a [bug](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/372) in NDK r15: it does not treat correctly the missing **android-25** folder. So, if your Android project has `minSdkVersion 25`, you should manually choose **APP_PLATFORM=android-24** (or **'-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24'** if you use cmake).

Comment: I wanted to build for android-9, did I need to download the ndk bellow r14?
Or is there any workaround to use the latest ndk (e.g r16) to build for old android api?

Comment: A binary for android-9 can be built with the latest NDK if you make no calls to APIs that were introduced later.

Answer (score 0):

From a chat with an android-ndk guy I know that `api 25` does not exist because "there were no new features since version 24".

Comment: There is ndk-14 which built for api 25, but still it is not stable version, there are some bugs.